# Is there a way to just take a slice of the string argument with format()?

Tags: python

With C like formatting we can put just a slice of the string argument within the string. For example, this:

```
print "I just love %.4s." %('cats and dogs')
```

will print this:

```
I just love cats.
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this using format() ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use basically the same format:

```
>>> print('I just love {0:.4}.'.format('cats and dogs'))
I just love cats.
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://pyformat.info/).

```
>>> print "I just love {:.4}.".format('cats and dogs')
I just love cats.
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases %-based formatting translates into {}-based formatting by adding a colon.

```
print "I just love %.4s." %('cats and dogs')
```

is equivalent to:

```
print "I just love {:.4s}.".format('cats and dogs')
```

You may omit the `s` in brackets, like this:

```
print "I just love {:.4}.".format('cats and dogs')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
print("I just love {:.4}".format('cats and dogs'))
```

https://pyformat.info/ - this site is an excellent resource to compare how to use `format` with "old style" format.